# Django Tastypie: including relationship with the same model

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I am really stuck with this issue. Here is a simplified version of a model:

```
# models.py
class CustomComment(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

So the comments can have children comments (there are only two levels though). So in the api when I query a comment I want to include the children. I have other models with relationship with other models but I can't find how to make a relationship within the same model. Here is what I tried:

```
# api.py
class CustomCommentResource(ModelResource):
    children = fields.ToManyField('self', 'children', related_name='parent_comment', null=True, blank=True, full=True) # returns an empty array

    class Meta:
        queryset = CustomComment.objects.filter(parent_comment=None, active=True)
        resource_name = 'comment'
```

With this code when I call the api the objects does have a `children` property, but it's an empty array.

Any idea how to get the comments, each comment including its own children?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want all the comments (for whatever these comments apply to) in a hierarchical structure, or just one comment and its immediate children?

Comment: @Aya Sorry I forgot to precise this, there is only two levels. There are just parents and children comments, the children cannot have children comments. In the response I want all the parents will all their children inside

Comment: Just to check: have you confirmed that the query you assign to `queryset` actually returns any objects? I notice your `active` field will default to `False`, but you're only selecting where `active=True`.

Comment: @Aya Yes the field is set the `True` when the objects are created. What I haven't thought about at first though is that in the query I also specify `parent_comment=None`. And the children won't have any parents. But I don't know if it's the same query that is used for the relationships. Plus, even when I remove this it does not return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I haven't thought about at first though is that in the query I
>   also specify `parent_comment=None`. And the children won't have any
>   parents.

Doesn't matter. The children will always be accessible from each parent via the related manager `parent.customcomment_set`.

> But I don't know if it's the same query that is used for the relationships.

No. It'll do a separate query for each parent to get to its children, although you might be able to do it in one query by using [`prefetch_related()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related).

The following code...

```
# api.py
class CustomCommentResource(ModelResource):
    children = fields.ToManyField('self', lambda bundle: bundle.obj.customcomment_set.all(), null=True, blank=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = CustomComment.objects.filter(parent_comment=None, active=True)
        resource_name = 'comment'
```

...works for me, but the docs for [`ToManyField`](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tomanyfield) aren't particularly good, so I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Holy smoke thank you so much, this works! And thanks also for the explanations.